# Extending MUI Theme Type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to extend MUI Theme, reading the docs I can see I need to do something like this

```
// theme.ts
import {
  type ThemeOptions as MuiThemeOptions,
  type Theme as MuiTheme,
} from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  type Theme = MuiTheme & {
    spacing: number[]
  };

  type ThemeOptions = MuiThemeOptions & {
     spacing: number[]
  };
}

// base.ts
import { type Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
export const base: Theme = {
  spacing: [0, 3, 6],
};
```

I would expect `base.ts` to use the new types that I defined but it doesn't look like it's working.

Is there anything else I need to do to make it work?